# Is Salesforce supporting JIT (just in time provisionning) over OpenID

Tags: apex, customer-community, single-sign-on, open-id-connect

We want to use OpenId SSO for our Salesforce Community Users provisionning
and I was wondering if Salesforce supports JIT (just in time provisionning) over OpenID (contact + account + user creation upon first login).

I didn't find any doc about that specific feature but I was wondering if it exists with an other naming or an other approach?

From what I understand the

> [Auth RegistrationHandler Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_auth_plugin.htm)

should provide this capacity for OpenId but can someone confirm ?

Comment: Yes. This works with Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass. But make sure you implement getUserInfo in custom plugin.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I can confirm that Auth RegistrationHandler Interface is perfectly fulfilling JIT provisionning for Community (even if the doc is not clearly stating about this use case).